# Using a class within another css selector

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, import, sass

Is there a way to set a css selector's style to be the same as another selector (class in this case) that was earlier defined without javascript?

specifically, my problem is applying bootstrap button classes (`btn-small`, `btn-mini`) to different buttons without changing it manually. The reason is that I am replacing the buttons with javascript and since I don't want to rewrite a lot of the code, I want the class to be exterior from the html

so instead of having

```
<div class="mini">
    <a class="btn btn-mini"> some_link </a>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="small">
    <a class="btn btn-small"> the_same_some_link </a> 
</div>
```

I could do

```
<div class="link small">
    <a class="btn"> the_same_some_link </a>
</div>
```

and using css do

```
.small a{
import .btn-small
}

.mini a{
import .btn-mini
}
```

could this be achieved with css or scss/sass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Sass by using [selector inheritance](http://sass-lang.com/) via `@extend`.

A solution with SCSS:

```
.small a{
  @extend .btn-small;
}

.mini a {
  @extend .btn-mini;
}
```

Edit: as noted in the comments, you also need to:

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap"
```

Comment: that means changing bootstrap css no?

Comment: Are you compiling bootstrap yourself or are you using it directly as CSS?

Comment: this should work, thanks. However I have another problem which isn't scss related.. I added @extend but it doesn't do anything..

Comment: Are you compiling your templates? I mean `@extend` is not part of standard CSS, its part of `Sass`. You need to compile your Sass templates into raw CSS in order to make it work.

Comment: its all in rails, so sass-rails takes care of this.. the problem appears to be that I `@extend` not from the same file.. if I `@extend` a class from that file it works well..

Comment: got it! needed to `@import "twitter/bootstrap"`

Comment: Great! Adding that as a tip in the answer for future visitors.